# In Kotlin, how can I test and use a value without computing it twice?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, filter, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

Every so often, I find myself wanting to compute a value for some sort of filter operation, but then wanting to use that value when it's already disappeared into the condition-checking thing.

For instance:

```
val found = list.firstOrNull { slowConversion(it).isWanted() }
if (found != null) {
   something(found, slowConversion(found))
}
```

or

```
when {
   other_conditions -> other_actions
   list.any { it.contains(regex1) } -> something(list.firstOrNull { it.contains(regex1) } ?: "!!??")
}
```

For the slowConversion() I can work with a sequence mapped to pairs, although the terms first and second kinda confuse things a bit...

```
val pair = list.asSequence().map { it to slowConversion(it) }.firstOrNull { it.second.isWanted() }
if ( pair != null ) {
  something(pair.first, pair.second)
}
```

or if I only want the conversion,

```
val converted = list.firstNotNullOfOrNull { slowConversion(it).takeIf { it.isWanted() } }
```

but the best I can come up with to avoid the `when` duplication involves moving the action part into the condition part!

```
fun case(s: List<String>, r: Regex) {
   val match = s.firstOrNull { it.contains(r) }?.also { something(it) }
   return match != null
}

when {
  other_conditions -> other_actions
  case(list, regex1) -> true
}
```

At this point, it seems I should just have a stack of function calls linked together with ||

```
other_things || case(list, regex1) || case(list, regex2) || catchAll(list)
```

Is there something better or more concise for either of these?

Comment: For the record, in simpler cases the idiomatic way to avoid repeating a value/expression/call (or using a temporary variable) is to use Kotlin's [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) , often in combination with the safe-call (`?.`) or elvis (`?:`) operators. But this question has more tricky cases, and I don't think any of the usual patterns will help much.

Comment: @gidds Ha, thanks - I use `?.also{}` often, but was more focused on whether there was a way to coalesce the`map` and `firstOrNull` like the awesomly named `firstNotNullofOrNull`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your first example like this:

```kotlin
for(element in list) {
    val result = slowConversion(element)
    if(result.isWanted()) {
        something(element, result)
        break
    }
}
```

This might not look very Kotlin-ish, but I think it's pretty straightforward & easy to understand.

For your second example, you can use the `find` function:

```kotlin
when {
    other_conditions -> other_actions
    else -> list.find { it.contains(regex1) }?.let(::something)
}
```

If you have multiple regexes, just iterate over them,

```kotlin
val regexes = listOf(regex1, regex2, ...)
for(regex in regexes) {
    val element = list.find { it.contains(regex1) } ?: continue
    something(element)
    break
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was getting too starry-eyed with the pretty syntax. Maybe there's scope for Kotlin to create more magic syntax, but the 'nope, no pretty magic way at the moment' is good enough for me. Cheers. :)